# Is there a way to overload a constructor with a 2D array (int)?

Tags: c++

When I utilize the default constructor, I expect it to call the constructor that accepts an argument; however, this does not occur correctly. When debugging, as far as I can tell it is assigning the values and then the instance simply isn't maintained. I'm not sure if I need to create a helper method instead to pass the object, array, assign out values, and then pass back the object?
My goal is to have a default constructor that passes a hard-coded set of values and then a constructor that accepts the same type of array passed as values.

I've tried passing the array as an argument for the constructors, and while it seems to work for the derived class, it does not work for the base class. I ended up moving the functionality of the overloaded constructor to the default constructor and that works correctly.

This is the base class:

```
// Puzzle.h
class Puzzle
{
public:
    Puzzle();
    Puzzle(int grid[gridLength][gridLength]);
    ~Puzzle();
    void Print_Puzzle(); // Displays puzzle in console

protected:
    int grid[gridLength][gridLength]; // Our board
private:


};
```

This is the definition:

```
Puzzle::Puzzle()
{
    int grid[gridLength][gridLength] = // Taken from https://www.puzzles.ca/sudoku_puzzles/sudoku_easy_505.html
    {
    { 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 9, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 6, 5, 4 },
    { 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3 },
    { 4, 0, 7, 9, 5, 0, 2, 6, 0 }
    };


    for (int x = 0; x < gridLength; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridLength; y++)
            Puzzle::grid[x][y] = grid[x][y];
    }
    // Puzzle::Puzzle(grid) // Doesn't work. Not sure how to properly pass the array values.
}

Puzzle::Puzzle(int grid[gridLength][gridLength])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < gridLength; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < gridLength; col++)
            this->grid[row][col] = grid[row][col];
    }
}
```

I expect the default constructor to pass the grid variable and the receiving constructor to assign those values to the instance's member property.

Comment: Use something like a `std::vector<std::vectory<int>>` maybe?

Comment: You can't call a constructor directly like a function, it's impossible. The closest thing might be a [delegating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) but that doesn't seem like it would help you much. Edit : Since your default grid is constant, make is a `static const` member and then you can use a delegating constructor.

Comment: So your real question has nothing to do with arrays but is about the right way to perform ctor delegation?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nooooooooo

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was thinking about using vectors but I wasn't sure how to maintain the 3x3 (9x9) grid approach with a vector. I understand that I could start it that way, but preventing it from being grown as the code expands - I just wasn't sure.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you, I will review the delegating constructor material again with the idea of doing a static const - that would make sense for the default. Eventually I am thinking of expanding the code to enable CSV input

Comment: @SeanBrookins Actually, if you make a `static const` member defining the default grid, you could simply provide is at the default argument for your constructor and not define a default constructor at all. Though you'll need to fix your constructor by adding `const` to the argument.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's what Francois is saying but I don't really know if that's correct or not.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see what you're saying - that makes sense! I would need to overload the constructor though to accept a const as well? I could modify the initial code I call it with from main() to pass a const variable since currently it's all hard-coded values, but I am thinking ahead to adding functionality that allows you to use filestreams - this wouldn't be static so I would have to have one that accepts non-static calls as well, correct? Is there a way I can I can use constructor syntax to extend it? like Puzzle(int grid[][] const) : Puzzle(int grid[][]) {}

Comment: @SeanBrookins You only need the `const` constructor because you never try to change the argument. No need for another overload. You can pass a non-`const` to a function that requires a `const`. No need to change the provided argument.

Comment: @SeanBrookins If you want to load a default grid from a file, then you should save that grid somewhere and provide it explicitly. You *could* have a `static` non-`const` member that you read from a file, but that sounds clunky.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm giving this a try - I tried to pass a non-const grid to the const ctor and it didn't work, but then I tried overloading a const and non const and it was fine. I delegated via PuzzleSolver::PuzzleSolver(const int grid[gridLength][gridLength]) : PuzzleSolver::PuzzleSolver(grid) {}

I have not yet attempted to switch to a vector system, that may take some re-designing.

Comment: *"I tried to pass a non-const grid to the const ctor and it didn't work"* [It does work](https://godbolt.org/z/z8O_Al). I'm not sure what the problem might be, but make sure you didn't try to do the opposite (pass `const` to non-`const`). Edit : Your delegation should not work though, it's passing a `const` array to a non-`const` argument. You are probably just calling the constructor itself in an infinite loop which [shouldn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/0BC54i).

Comment: Follow up : It seems some compilers won't diagnose the problem mentioned in the last part of my previous comment.

Comment: Ugh, somehow my local copy that I brought home from work didn't include any of the changes I made today. I am going to start over, I'll try again - I think I was passing a constant variable to a non-constant ctor as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more convenient way and no less efficient is to use `std::array` which can be copied, so that you do not have to copy it element-wise:

```
#include <array>

constexpr int gridLength = 9;
using Grid = std::array<std::array<int, gridLength>, gridLength>;

Grid const grid = {{ // Taken from https://www.puzzles.ca/sudoku_puzzles/sudoku_easy_505.html
{ 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 9, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 0, 0, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 6, 5, 4 },
{ 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3 },
{ 4, 0, 7, 9, 5, 0, 2, 6, 0 }
}};

class Puzzle {
    Grid grid_;
public:
    Puzzle(Grid const& grid)
        : grid_(grid) // Copy grid into grid_.
    {}
};

int main() {
    Puzzle p(grid);
}
```

---

Alternatively:

```
class Puzzle {
    Grid grid_;

    static Grid make_grid() {
        Grid grid;
        // Your code to fill the grid.
        return grid;
    }

public:
    Puzzle()
        : Puzzle(make_grid())
    {}

    Puzzle(Grid const& grid)
        : grid_(grid) // Copy the grid.
    {}
};
```

Comment: The problem is that OP wants the default constructor to delegate to `Puzzle::Puzzle(int[][])` after calculating a default grid. Notice the attempted call to `Puzzle::Puzzle(grid)` at the end of `Puzzle::Puzzle();`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think OP wants to pass an array to the constructor, but cannot, hence he does that loop. Not that he would like to call another constructor after that loop.

Comment: I'll refer you to *"I expect the default constructor to pass the grid variable and the receiving constructor to assign those values to the instance's member property."* and `// Puzzle::Puzzle(grid) // Doesn't work. Not sure how to properly pass the array values.` The last part is a comment on the line not working, but the problem is not actually passing an array. It's calling the constructor.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Judging from the code, `grid` is not changed but copied into `this->grid`.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does *now* but the goal seems to be to get the other constructor (which does the same thing) to do it instead. The local `grid` is essentially the default grid to use. It might as well be `const`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Yes, Francois is correct - I am sorry for the confusion. Currently, I copy the values and so using your suggestion would be perfect for the current setup; however, I would like to be able to call the proper constructor code using the default constructor. If this method would be more efficient, I do not have a reason to NOT do it the way you're suggesting - I am just trying to learn the best way to do this and understand :)

Comment: @SeanBrookins Added an alternative solution for you.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you are committing a design error.
Never use C arrays in C++, use std::vector or std::array instead.
Try this.

```
class Sudoku
{
public:

    Sudoku(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> initData = { {/* Write your default values here */} }) 
    {
        data = initData;
    }

private:

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
};
```

if you want to use C-like arrays you will need to understand the only way to pass arrays is via pointers, and is a messy solution.

```
template <uint32_t width, uint32_t height>
class Sudoku
{
public:

    Sudoku(int** initData, int maxX, int maxY)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxX; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxY; j++) {
                data[i][j] = initData[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

private:

    std::array<width, std::array<height, int>> data;
};
```

Comment: Nooooo never nest `std::vector`s

Comment: is the "best" way to imitate a 2D array. I will gladly use a std::map with a struct position consisting in an "x" and "y" position, but we need to make sacrifices.

Comment: @RobertoP.Romero I don't think that's what was implied. If you are using nested `std::vector` or `std::array` to represent a rectangular value space, you can just use a flat `std::vector` instead, mapping coordinates to single indices like `vect[x + y * width]` instead. It helps with locality, but it's not usually a big deal.

Comment: _"is the "best" way to imitate a 2D array"_ It certainly is not. And you don't need a map. You can make a 1D vector with 2D indices mapped on top of it, with no sacrifices (and substantial benefits). Nested vectors are incredibly wasteful. They're like hiring a bus so there's enough room for each of your passengers to ride their bikes onto it ... instead of just having them sit in a car.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If utilizing a 1D Vector with 2D indices mapped would be a better approach, is there a chance of you recommending a reference or showing me an example? I haven't done a lot with maps yet, and I am not entirely certain how you would go about implementing this solution. It sounds like you would use a vector of x,y coordinates and the coordinates would correspond to the map that would have values stored there for the pairs? Is that right?

Comment: @SeanBrookins It's just high school arithmetic! _Index(i,j) = Data(i + j*width)_. Write a little class that wraps a vector and provides 2D indexing operators/functions, which apply said arithmetic to access the 1D data. Easy! There are a few implementation examples online that you can look for; [I've posted a few on SO over the years](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A560648+is%3Aanswer+matrix)

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit this is perfect. I will update my code accordingly. I was only expecting to find help on the constructor :); if I do it this way, I am guessing that I should create a default static vector like with the array?

Comment: @SeanBrookins Yep sounds good (though you'll now be able to just ctor-initialise it with a `{1,2,3,4}` if you like too)

Comment: @RobertoP.Romero To be clear, when I say "mapping", I mean mathematically. No `std::map`s at all. Any additional container would ruin the purpose of doing this